# IntelliJ add spark source compiled code as jar

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, spark-streaming, intellij-14

I'm trying to add spark as jar in IntelliJ. The reason I'm doing this is beacause I need to add few new xml-s like *hive-site.xml* and etc into **configuration** folder of spark.

I don't know how to add it other then that way. Has someone tried that?
Sorry if this is noob question but :S

P.S. I'm using SBT and currently using spark2 as libDependencie in *build.sbt* but on that way I can't find spakr2 config file to set *hive-site.xml* file in it so he can use it.

Edit: 
I'm using **SparkSession**

Comment: You can provide hive-site.xml in run profile of your application as argument

Comment: I don't want run spark-app via `spark-submit` but through **run** button in intelliJ as test localy

Comment: If you use it in a local application with a Jar file, you can add the config option to the Spark config object during creation. Or simply put hive-site.xml to the classpath

Comment: Can you explain me how to set classpath in intelliJ? :)